# Create and append a table to databricks using nested data from json

Tags: python, json, databricks, azure-databricks

I am generating a series of data nested in json and would like to append these files automatically to a table within the databricks. I don't have her schema ... this data will go to azure storage.

```
%python
# !/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import sys
import json
import os
import pandas as pd

def create_table():
    qry = """
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE vsts 
    USING json
    OPTIONS (path 'dbfs:/mnt/lake/vsts/*.json')
    """
    return spark.sql(qry)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_table()
```

I tried to create a temporary table and then put the new data into a permanent table but this process did not work. Basically I need to insert the hundreds of files that will be created with data nested in a single table.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import sys
import json
import os

def get_clear_default():
    qry_default = """
    select * from vsts
    """
    return spark.sql(qry_default)

def create_table():
    qry = """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db_sandbox`.`tst_vsts` 
    USING JSON
    OPTIONS (
    path 'dbfs:/mnt/lake/vsts/*.json'
    )
    """
    return spark.sql(qry)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_table()
```

Answer (score 0):

We can probably try this route.

```
df=spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("<Azure_Path>")

df.createOrReplaceTempView("test")
```

Then you can start using this 'test' table in set of Spark SQLs for creating table.

If in case you want to split down the array of elements in nested JSON then try POS Explode for denormalizing them into table.

```
        spark.sql("SELECT \
              n.pos AS position, \
              n.<unique_field> AS <unique_field>, \
              <field1>[pos] AS <field1>, \
              <field2>[pos] AS <field2>, \
              <field3>[pos] AS <field3>\
       FROM \
              test \
       LATERAL VIEW POSEXPLODE(<parent_field>.<unique_field>) n AS pos, <unique_field>").show()
```